# Could anyone tell me why my setTimeout function within the try block does not work?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dialogflow-es, settimeout

I have a problem. Could anyone tell me why my setTimeout function within the try block does not work? It doesn't wait for 10000 milliseconds and simple runs through.
As a result, the console shows the error message "cannot read property data of "undefined".
The API should return an object, but needs some time to fetch the answer.
The console.log(responseInformation) returns also "undefined".

```
const fetchAnswerFromDialogflow = 
try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents:batchUpdate`,
        node,
        config
      );

      const waitForResponseAssignment = async () => {
        let nodesSavedToChatbot = await res.response.data;
        return nodesSavedToChatbot;
      };

      const responseInformation = setTimeout(
        await waitForResponseAssignment(),
        10000
      );
      
      console.log(responseInformation);
```

Comment: your code doesnt make sense

Comment: setTimeout is not the correct solution to the actual problem you're having.

Comment: how can i make java script wait until it has received the answer from the API?

Comment: It does already, with `await`. The real problem is that you're trying to access `res.response.data` when it should (probably) be just `res.data`.

Comment: Accessing the result of an asynchronous operation, yet to be performed, in synchronous code that requests the operation is not possible. End of story. The code needs to rewritten to handle results asynchronously. Bear in mind the `await` operator is *not* available in synchronous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems in your code:

```
const res = await axios.post(
  `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents:batchUpdate`,
  node,
  config
);

const waitForResponseAssignment = async () => {
   /*
    axios response doesnt have a property called response,
    so res.response.data is error.
    Also res.data is already a response from the api(res is
    not a promise so you dont have to use await below, 
    even you dont need this `waitForResponseAssignment` function)
   */
  let nodesSavedToChatbot = await res.response.data;
  return nodesSavedToChatbot;
};

// This timeout function is not correct, setTimeout
// accepts the first param as callback(but you passed a value)
// Actually you also dont need this `setTimeout`
const responseInformation = setTimeout(
  await waitForResponseAssignment(),
  10000
);
```

You can just use the below code:

```
const res = await axios.post(
  `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents:batchUpdate`,
  node,
  config
);
return res.data;
```